# Ran out of space on first partition, how do I integrate new partition into the file system?

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have Ubuntu 20.04 running in a VMWare Workstation virtual machine. I originally set it up for a 20GB virtual disk. That is now full so I added 30GB. However, it is a separate partition. I formatted that with GParted. But now I want to integrate it into the existing directory system in such a way that the space issue with the first partition is solved. Thought most of the data is in /snap (it's not, it's in /usr and /var) , but I unsuccessfully tried to mount to /snap if that is in fact a possibility.

Comment: I’ve not used VMWare myself but on Virtualbox you can just increase the size of the original disk and filesystems. You can probably do that on VMWare too

Comment: If you mount the new disk to /snap it will hide the original contents. If you want to do it that way I’d move the contents of /snap to the new disk and then mount it. You might find issues with that on the running system so perhaps use a live environment to make the change. You will need to edit fstab to mount it at boot time. Make sure you have a backup of the whole system first

Comment: @PonJar I used VMWare in years past and I have a recollection of just increasing the space at the VMWare Workstation level and not having to deal with Linux (although I also used Virtualbox in the past so may be confusing them). But I don't see that capability here and it says "Expand only increases the size of the virtual disk. Sizes of partitions and file systems are not affected."  I don't know if there was an option I missed when I created it that allowed a disk that was variable in size and the underlying OS would automatically catch it.

Comment: @PonJar I can't find anything about moving files to a partition that is unmounted. How would I reference that partition in "mv" or "cp" commands?

Comment: If you can expand the virtual disk you can achieve what you want by expanding the system partition and filesystem. GParted will do this for you but you need to boot to a live environment (Ubuntu installation media but select "Try Ubuntu" not "Install Ubuntu".) Always wise to have a backup before you start.

Comment: To use mv or cp commands the target disk needs to be mounted so something like sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /tmp should work. Just confirm you have a /tmp directory first to mount to and check the sd-- bit is correct for your setup. Then use mv -r {source} {target}. {source} will be the contents of your snaps directory. {target} will be /tmp or wherever you chose to mount.